# Managing user auth in a single page app

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, angularjs, facebook-graph-api

I've troubles in understanding how to apply my scenario in AngularJS.
My application has some pages that must perform operations similar to those (all operations are client-side):

1. Authorize the user via an internal API call (say `/user/auth`). If the user has authorized before with Facebook, it gives me also FB's `access_token`
2. Get the FB pages in which the user is admin via Facebook Graph API
3. Populate a table with those pages

The pages are in some sense all little one-page web apps have all a similar structure (get user auth then fetch data from FB or the internal API and do something in the DOM).

Let's say I've a controller like:

```
<ul ng-controller='PagesController'>
    <li ng-repeat='p in pages'> ... </li>
</ul>
```

My temporary solution would use **jQuery's promises** like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    MyApp.FBInit(); // initialize with FB.init
    MyApp.authUser().then(getThePages).then(populateTable);
});
```

This is not elegant, not modular and I must access the `PagesController`'s scope with some Javascript magic:

```
function getThePages() { 
    var d = $.Deferred();
    // etc etc, make call to graph and resolve the deferred if ok and put
    // the result in MyApp.pages
    return d.promise();
}

function populateTable() {
    MyApp.applyToScope("#pages","pages",MyApp.pages.data);
);

// definition of MyApp.applytoScope()....
function(controllerElement, model, value) {
    var scope = Splashmood.angular.getScope(controllerElement);
    scope.$apply(function ($scope) {$scope[model] = value;});
}
```

I just can't figure out how to port this functionality all in AngularJS with the use of **services** (factory).

My thought was to create something similar to this:

```
app.factory("UserAuthFactory", function ($http, $q) {
    // do something
});

app.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $http, UserAuthFactory) {
    // do something
});

app.factory("FbUserPages", function ($http, $q) {
    var endpoint = "me/accounts";
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.getPages = function() {
        return ....; // $http calling Facebook Graph API
    }
    return dataFactory;
});

app.controller('MyFbPagesController', function ($scope, $http, FbUserPages) {

    var handleSuccess = function (data, status) {
        $scope.pages = data;
    }

    $scope.pages = [];
    FbUserPages.getPages().success(handleSuccess);
});
```

but I can't figure out how to make the processes synchronous (run this and other controllers **only** if user is authorized!).